# Warned current user about for logging out the account

Tags: django, session

How can I warned the User that his/her account needs to be logged out because it logged in in other sessions

The code for preventing multiple session in django is in this http://www.jiajianhudong.com/question/1991002.html

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically/Forcefully logout user if he is already login using Qsessions package https://pypi.org/project/django-qsessions/

Comment: Then how can I warn the user that they need to log out?